# How work with contracts accros without synchonize

Tags: contract-development, web3js, web3.py

How I can call method my contracts without synchonize? Synchronize is long and has big size.
Language: Python or Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a service like [infura.io](https://infura.io/) that provides public nodes. You have to register and they generate a url you can use from your application.

Comment: How do I specify my wallet for transactions?

Comment: That depends on your framework. Truffle has instructions in their page http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider.